# Is Divine Smite considered a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, paladin

Divine Smite is a supernatural ability, but at the same time it consumes spell slots on use.

Is Divine Smite considered a spell?

If it is considered a supernatural ability then *silence*/*antimagic field*s do not affect it. On the other hand, if it is considered a spell, a paladin cannot use *misty step* and Divine Smite at the same time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## No

Mechanically speaking, a Divine Smite is a Paladin class ability. Meanwhile, a spell is anything listed in PHB pages 207-211, which shows the spell list for all classes. So even though Divine Smites use spell slots, they are not spells.

#### Not all spells consume spell slots

From PHB 201:

> Some characters and monsters have special abilities that let them cast spells without using spell slots.

Therefore, spells and spell slots do not *have* to be tied together, though they usually are. Spells can be cast without spell slots. Just because something consumes a spell slot doesn't mean it has to be a spell.

#### Antimagic Field does affect it

While a Divine Smite is not a spell, it is magical. "Magical things" is a larger set that contains all spells.

Antimagic Field specifies:

> Spells *and other magical effects*, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can’t protrude into it.

It specifically states:

> **Targeted Effects.** Spells ***and other magical effects***, such as *magic missile* and *charm person*, that target a creature or an object in the sphere have no effect on that target.

As Divine Smite is a magical effect, it is nullified in an Antimagic Field.

#### It does work in an area of *silence*

Divine Smite is not a spell and requires no verbal spell components. All it requires is you hit with a weapon and you expend a spell slot.

> Starting at 2nd level, when you hit a creature with a melee weapon attack, you can expend one paladin spell slot to deal radiant damage to the target

Comment: RAW, there's nothing in the rules that identifies Divine Smite as magical. [Sage Advice](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SA-Compendium.pdf) addresses the topic of what's magical and what isn't (see "Is the breath weapon of a dragon magical?") and Divine Smite doesn't fit any of the criteria. It's probably *intended* to be magical since it uses spell slots, but it'd be good to edit the answer to be less definitive about that.

Comment: In addition, Divine Smite cannot be counterspelled.

Comment: It does radiant damage, FWIW.

Comment: @markovchain Doval has a strong argument here (probably should be an answer), but are you willing to adjust yours or are you firmly rooted in Magical Ability? See also [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88559/does-antimagic-field-supress-all-divine-magic) and [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88603/does-improved-divine-smite-work-in-an-antimagic-field/88605#88605). If you feel you don't want to change, please let me know and I'll submit a new answer.

Comment: @NautArch [Crawford revisited some Sage Advice answers](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/rules-references-august-2017), and the one I quoted earlier has been updated to include features fueled by spell slots, so Divine Smite is officially magical now. Note, however, that [Improved Divine Smite is not](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/897256870267691008).

Comment: @Doval: Note: Your first link (in your last comment) no longer works, due to the D&D website being restructured. You may want to link to an archived version of the page, or simply link to the current version of the Sage Advice Compendium.