# Does Tenser's Transformation work with Divine Smite and Psychic Blades?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing

This question concerns a multi-classed Bard (College of Whispers)/Paladin who has acquired the spell Tenser's Transformation as a magical secret.

Could such a bard use their Psychic Blades feature to add damage to their attacks? What about using the Divine Smite to empower their attacks?

I understand you can't cast spells while under the effect of Tenser's Transformation - but can you either of the above options to deal more damage?

Comment: Thanks mucly L0neGamer - it is clearer with your changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You can use Psychic Blades and Divine Smite during Tenser's Transformation

Tenser's Transformation prevents the target (usually the caster) from casting spells during the duration of the spell. Neither Psychic Blades nor Divine Smite are casting spells (Psychic Blades uses Bardic Inspiration, question on divine smite [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104414/is-smite-considered-a-spell)), therefore you can use both during the spell's duration.

One caveat is that Psychic Blades only allows you to deal extra damage once per round on your turn, so you can only deal this damage once per turn.

One big downside with performing this manoeuvre is that you will quickly burn through all of your resources - but if you need to, this is a good way to deal a lot of damage quickly while in melee.

Comment: Thank you muchly, L0neGamer! And it seems to me that relatively speaking, given the amount of damage one will do the downside is nay that great - esp. for the Bard's relatively lackluster 4th level spell slots...